# UltiDev ASP.NET page hangs and then times out

Tags: asp.net, .net, webserver, session-timeout, ultidev

I have a very simple ASP.NET (4.0) page that I am serving up with UltiDev Web Server Pro.
When I click a button I do a

```
Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx")
```

All works fine until I leave the page in my browser for some time (I can't tell you a specific amount of time but it is a few minutes). I then click on the button and after about a minute or more of waiting for a page load I get:

Firefox:

```
'The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.'
```

IE9:

```
'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'
```

If I refresh everything works fine again until a period of inactivity - any suggestions?

I tried this in IIS and that does not seem to have the same issue.

**EDIT:**

I tried hosting the exact same project on a Windows XP machine and this seems to work without issue. So I think it could be something to do with either Windows 7 64 bit or just Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you do not have another redirect upon the Page_Load, cause this would cause an `Exception` and it might cause the same error you are describing.

Good luck!

Comment: No other redirect (in fact no other code in the page at all) and it all works fine until it is left for a few minutes so there are no exceptions being thrown

Comment: Try creating a new project. Also try to change the port number; this could work.

Comment: This *is* a new project. Why would changing the port number have any effect?